# Listbox item is not getting fired

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, click, listitem

I am using listbox inside panorama, like if panorama has 5 items then each panorama item contains a listbox.

The listitem is not getting fired at times, mainly for the second time. For the first them when the list item is clicked then it navigates to next page. When i come back and again i tap on the listitem is not getting fired.

Am using SelectionChanged for list click listener.

I have got a suggestion from web search to use stackpannel instead of grid in , but in some places am unable to use stack pannel because of the component arrangement.

Please suggest me does changing to stackpannel is the only way or is there any other solution for this.

Any kind of ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When one item is selected in a ListBox, it keeps the record of the selectedindex. When the same element is tapped again, there is no change in the selectedindex and hence the SelectionChanged is not fired. Hence what you can do is setting the selectedindex back to -1 after each selection or after the back navigation to the listbox page

```
//In the onnavigatedto function, set the listbox selectedindex to -1
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MyListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

And modify your selectionchanged event like this

```
 private void MyListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //let our code run only if index is not -1
        if (MyListBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            //Your selectionchanged code
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps

UPDATE:  For your Panorama case

```
private void MyListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox listbox = (sender as ListBox);
        //let our code run only if index is not -1
        if (listbox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            //Your selectionchanged code
            At the end of it set the index back to -1
            listbox.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. This worked in all other pages. But only in one page i have a problem that the listbox is inside panorama's datatemplate. am unable to access it. I have 5 panorama items and each item has 1 listbox.